# JavaScript Array: Exchanging displayed content

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a page where *on click* it swaps div content for the new array.  I don't want the div to be empty on page load and then something displayed on click, I want it to start with one array and then on click change to the other.

Here are my arrays:

(When page loads)

```
var food = [{logo:'img', name:'Pizza'}{logo:'img', name:'French Fries'}];
```

(On click)

```
var clothes = [{logo:'img', name:'T Shirt'}{logo:'img', name:'Black Turtleneck'}]; 

document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = food[0];
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = food[1];
```

The div ids are "choice1" and "choice2"

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<img id="choice1" src="" alt="...">
<div class="caption">
</br>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="choice1Function()" role="button">Select</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

What would you use to make the swap?

Comment: And what it's the question?

Comment: what would you use to make the swap?

Comment: show markup for "choice1" and "choice2" elements

Comment: Ah yeah good catch there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` inside function which represents element that was clicked, also you need to select properties from object you want to use `food[0].name`

```js
var food = [{
  logo: 'img',
  name: 'Pizza'
}, {
  logo: 'img',
  name: 'French Fries'
}];

function choice1Function(e) {
  e.innerHTML = food[0].name;
}

function choice2Function(e) {
  e.innerHTML = food[1].name;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="choice1Function(this)" role="button">Select</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="choice2Function(this)" role="button">Select</a></p>
```